# what is the unit of timeit() from python3 timeit module function

Tags: python, python-3.5, timeit

```
import time
import timeit
start = timeit.timeit()

time.sleep(5)

end = timeit.timeit()

time_elapsed = end - start
print(end)
print(time_elapsed)
print(start)
```

Outputs:

```
0.018255482330552297
-0.00033663523232263515
0.018592117562874932
```

Comment: Seconds, as float. [Documentation is your friend](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/timeit.html

Answer (score 2):

As [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit) clearly says:

> This… returns the time it takes to execute the main statement a number of times, measured in seconds as a float.

---

Meanwhile, notice that this is the elapsed time to run the main statement—that is, nothing at all, in your case. It's not a timestamp or anything like that. So subtracting `end - start` doesn't give you anything useful—it's the difference in elapsed time for two different runs of a no-op.

Comment: ...and since there is no main statement, it doesn't take long to execute...